# JQuery Datatable custom sorting first column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable - 1.9.4.

I have a gird with html elements inside it. Like drop-down, textbox.

I have implemented the custom sorting for the drop-down column. And the code is as shown below.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['select-sort-desc'] = function (x, y) {
       x = $(x).find('option:selected').text();
       y = $(y).find('option:selected').text();
 }
```

Once the page is loaded and jQuery datatable is initialized. Sorting is working properly.

Also, we have functionality to add new rows to the grid.
So, once the new rows are added to the grid. I have re-initialized the datatable.

But, sorting for the new rows added is not working only for the first column which contains html drop-down inside it.